# NumPy Secondary Sorting

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I'm having the following simple array :

```
a = np.array([
             [1, 1000, 58],
             [1, 200, 69],
             [3, 300, 34],
             [4, 400, 82]], dtype = int)
```

When I issue the following `lexsort()` command :  `i = np.lexsort((a[:,0], a[:,1]))`

I'm getting :

```
array([[   1,  200,   69],
       [   3,  300,   34],
       [   4,  400,   82],
       [   1, 1000,   58]])
```

While I was expecting :

```
array([[   1,  200,   69],
       [   1, 1000,   58],
       [   3,  300,   34],
       [   4,  400,   82],
   ])
```

Can anyone explain me why ? and how do I get the expected output ?

Comment: [Read the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) - `The last key in the sequence is used for the primary sort order, the second-to-last key for the secondary sort order, and so on.`.

Answer (score 3):

Following @Divakar comment. All I had to do is :

`i = np.lexsort((a[:,1], a[:,0]))`

Thank you